# Can I retrieve metadata when using "listobjects" on S3 in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

I can retrieve basic information using "listObjects" but would like to get each objects metadata without doing another request. At the moment I'm using:

```
var bucket = new AWS.S3({
    params: {
        Bucket: 'Bucketname',
        Prefix: req.body.params.objectId + '/',
        Delimiter: '/'
    }
});

bucket.listObjects(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Could not load objects from S3');
    } else {
        res.json(data);
    }
});
```

This returns

```
CommonPrefixes: Array[0]
Contents: Array[1]
Delimiter: "/"
IsTruncated: false
Marker: ""
MaxKeys: 1000
Name: "encore-storage"
Prefix: "Music/Demos/song.mp3"
```

But I would love to get the meta-data such as the "ContentType" without making another call for each object.